# Remove specific characters after matching substring with Perl grep

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I use the following expression to get the second item of a line of text.

```
/\s(.*?) /
```

An example output might be `23:55:01`. Can I also remove the colons in the same expression?

Example input is:

> 16-03-17 05:00:02 JRTF: ...

Everything after the *...* should be superfluous. In this case I need to extract `050002`.

**EDIT** (now a Perl / grep question):

The reason I need to do this is so I get all values which are greater than the current time.

I am currently doing this the following way using grep in Perl:

```
my @windowLog = grep {
        join("", split(":", (split(" ", $_))[1])) > $UTCTime
} @oldLog;
```

Where `@oldLog` is an array of strings which look like the above example, and `$UTCTime` is the current time.

Seems pretty inefficient and untidy.

Comment: use another replace code to remove colons.

Comment: can you show your input text line and desired extracted output?

Comment: @ritesht93 Sure thing - done.

Comment: you'll need to use regex substitution, `^(\S*)\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\s(.*)^`  would be the regex and substitute with `\2\3\4`. If you can mention your regex flavor/programming lang you are using, then i can provide an example too

Comment: @ritesht93 Thanks - I've updated the question so it's now also a grep and Perl question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write

```
my @windowLog = grep { (split)[1] =~ tr/://dr > $UTCTime } @oldLog;
```